# Working Implementations of BIP85

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed, private-key-format, bip85-deterministic-entropy

Can anyone point me to working implementations of BIP85?

The only one I'm aware of is the Coldcard Wallet implementation.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (2020-08-13) there are seem to be none. I've [opened](https://github.com/BlockchainCommons/bc-seedtool-cli/issues/24) [some](https://github.com/iancoleman/bip39/issues/424) tickets. Hopefully developers find some time to implement.

Answer (score 0):

check out https://github.com/scgbckbone/btc-hd-wallet

Besides the iancoleman app, as of 2022-02 I only know of Coldcard & AirGap Vault.

See the spec for libraries

Python library implementation: https://github.com/ethankosakovsky/bip85

JavaScript library implementation: https://github.com/hoganri/bip85-js